# Laravel, how to merge Many array with array itself from foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

when i try:

```
echo $response;
```

the output is LIKE (similiar):

```
{
    "identity": {
        "result": [
            {
                "name" = "Dilan",
                "place_id" = 1
            },
            {
                "name" = "Milea",
                "place_id" = 1
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "identity": {
        "result": [
            {
                "name" = "Ariel",
                "place_id" = 2
            },
            {
                "name" = "Noah",
                "place_id" = 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

nah when i try to echo $response['identity'], the output is shows the first array only, all my operation to $response is only applied for first array only, i can't do any operation to the second array.

what i want is merged all array output into 1 array, LIKE this below:

```
{
    {
        "identity": {
            "result": [
                {
                    "name" = "Dilan",
                    "place_id" = 1
                },
                {
                    "name" = "Milea",
                    "place_id" = 1
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "identity": {
            "result": [
                {
                    "name" = "Ariel",
                    "place_id" = 2
                },
                {
                    "name" = "Noah",
                    "place_id" = 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

here my controller

[image]

thank you! your help is very needed^^

Comment: you don't need to merge .  you need to loop over `$response` and perform task because if merge then it will be same as before `(as you mention above merge code)`

Comment: btw the output of $response is string, when i try to convert to array like $test = json_decode($response, true); dd($test);  then, its only execute the first array which only dump the first array only

Comment: I don't think doing `echo $response;` will output an array. How do you build the "array" ?

Comment: its not a array but a json_encoded

Comment: @executable when i try dd($response); without doing json_decode, the output is still the first array only

Comment: What is `dd($test);` ?

Comment: can you add more details , also in array

Comment: @executable sry xD i mean dd($response); only shows the first array

Comment: can you show what you are returning from the controller mate.

Comment: i have edited the Question, i've add the controller img

Comment: can you try doing `var_dump(json_decode($response));`

Comment: @executable its only show the first array, but when i try var_dump($response); without json_decode(), its shows all of array data

Comment: What have you tried to merge such data? Please share your attempts in readable form (as in: code is shared best as text, not as images!)

Answer (score 1):

why yo need to do this,
you can marge all  "result" in one array like this

```
$allResult =[]; 
foreach($arrayes as $array){

      $allResult = array_merge($allResult,$array['identity']['result']);
 }
```

Comment: but its not dynamic, when the $response is showing 5 array, i think i can't use this code, btw thanks for response!

Comment: if you need to dynamic it use 
```
$allResult =[];
foreach($arrayes as $array){
$allResult = array_merge($allResult,$array['identity']['result']);
} 

```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is about your json syntax. because you should write

```
[
    {"identity": {
        ...
    }}
]
```

instead of:

```
{
    {"identity": {
        ...
    }}
}
```

---

please pay attention to first brackets and accolades. in your json sample "indentifies" must define in an array and at last pass it into a loop that my suggest is foreach iterates. but it's not neccesary to use loop and you can access to every indices of your array with its key. json sample and code:

```
<?php

// json
$json = '[{
    "identity": {
        "result": [{
            "name": "Dilan",
            "place_id": 1
        }, {
            "name": "Milea",
            "place_id": 1
        }]
    }
}, {
    "identity": {
        "result": [{
            "name": "Ariel",
            "place_id": 2
        }, {
            "name": "Noah",
            "place_id": 2
        }]
    }
}]';

// decode json
$json = json_decode($json, true);

// pass your json to foreach
foreach($json as $json_index){

    // print every indice to process it
    print_r($json_index);
    
    // or getting your result parameters
    foreach($json_index['identity']['result'] as $result){
        echo($result['name'] . ' = ' . $result['place_id']);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

}



// or



print_r($json[1]);
?>
```

Comment: ok thanks for that response, i can do that, but i cant get the value from an element of that array, its still shows the first array when i try to dd($json); but when print_r or var_dump ($json), its shows all of array data

Comment: @MuhammadRobbiZulfikar i tested my code and it was ok. it show every each loop "name" param. but i don't got your mean. please w8 for others. maybe them can solve your problem